# What ways can I get Tower Bux?

Tags: tiny-tower

In what ways can I get Tower Bux in Tiny Towers (besides buying it with RLM)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get Bux by:

- Locating a person when someone asks you to find them: 1 Bux (this is easiest when you have very few floors and not worth the time when you have very very many floors)
- Fully Stocking a floor (most of the time you just get coins): 1 Bux
- Tips from bitizens using the elevator (usually coins, again): 1 Bux
- Employing a bitizen in his or her dream job (always, the first time per bitizen only though): 2 Bux
- Completing missions: Rate and task depends on the mission
- Birthdays: Your bitizens have birthdays, and on their birthday you get a Bux: 1 Bux

The easiest way to get lots of bux, if you have a large number of residential/commercial floors, is to evict bitizens that don't have their dream job and pay Bux to get new bitizens to replace them. If you have the majority of different floor types, more often than not these bitizens will be able to give you 2 bux, netting 1 bux after losing one to instantly move in the new bitizen. Even if you have all skill level 9 employees in their dream job, you can still swap out one of your level 9 employees for the new one and then immediately put the first one back again, evicting the inferior employee, but still getting your 2 bux for giving them their dream job. In this way you can slowly but steadily accumulate bux, as long as you have empty apartment slots to move bitizens into. This is why the wiki recommends keeping as many residential floors as possible with only four residents, as any bitizen who arrives at a floor with vacancies will move in and save you the one bux you would otherwise pay to move someone in.

Comment: Apparently, you can also get Bux from doing minor jobs for the Christmas event (I think()

Comment: @Retrosaur oh huh I haven't played since they introduced that

Comment: Ahh. Well, they just ask you to find a "person", and once you tap on that person, you get 1 bux.

Comment: @Retrosaur oooohh That's not just for Christmas, they always do that...I just totally forgot about it.

Comment: Don't forget about birthdays. Apparently the wiki says on the bit's birthday you get one towerbux

Comment: Also (i) the free bux (or coins) gifted daily by NimbleBit over the recent holidays (just by opening the app daily) and (ii) I remember long ago that NB gifted bux when it was one of the developers birthdays!

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you have a Sushi Bar, You can do a glitch with a free job space,
Tap the job place and quickly tap it again with no names, It will say (null) has his/her dream job, If you give someone/null their dream job, you get 2 tower bux.
It doesn't take a spot, so you can repeat over and over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them by getting a sushi bar and then hire 2 people then stock the best one with 2 people then delete one finally u have to click on hire really fast then straight after click on the Newley stocked 2nd item